# Can't upload images in Wordpress 4.9.5

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, image-processing, image-uploading

I've been wrestling with this for 2 days, I've tried everything that Google searching for 2 days has to offer, and still I can't get it to work. Basically, when I'm editing a page and adding a "featured image" the upload is interrupted and all I'm left with is the blue progress bar. I opened the console and I see that there's a an error that reads "/wp-admin/async-upload.php 404 (Not Found)" in "load-scripts.php?c=0&load%5B%5D=jquery-core,jquery-migrate,utils,moxiejs,plupload&ver=4.9.5:12".

```
load-scripts.php?c=0&load[]=jquery-core,jquery-migrate,utils,moxiejs,plupload&ver=4.9.5:9 JQMIGRATE: Migrate is installed, version 1.4.1
load-scripts.php?c=0&load[]=jquery-core,jquery-migrate,utils,moxiejs,plupload&ver=4.9.5:12 POST http://www.handi-gamer.com/wp-admin/async-upload.php 404 (Not Found)
send @ load-scripts.php?c=0&load[]=jquery-core,jquery-migrate,utils,moxiejs,plupload&ver=4.9.5:12
exec @ load-scripts.php?c=0&load[]=jquery-core,jquery-migrate,utils,moxiejs,plupload&ver=4.9.5:11
shimExec @ load-scripts.php?c=0&load[]=jquery-core,jquery-migrate,utils,moxiejs,plupload&ver=4.9.5:11
exec @ load-scripts.php?c=0&load[]=jquery-core,jquery-migrate,utils,moxiejs,plupload&ver=4.9.5:11
e @ load-scripts.php?c=0&load[]=jquery-core,jquery-migrate,utils,moxiejs,plupload&ver=4.9.5:12
i @ load-scripts.php?c=0&load[]=jquery-core,jquery-migrate,utils,moxiejs,plupload&ver=4.9.5:12
send @ load-scripts.php?c=0&load[]=jquery-core,jquery-migrate,utils,moxiejs,plupload&ver=4.9.5:12
f @ load-scripts.php?c=0&load[]=jquery-core,jquery-migrate,utils,moxiejs,plupload&ver=4.9.5:14
r @ load-scripts.php?c=0&load[]=jquery-core,jquery-migrate,utils,moxiejs,plupload&ver=4.9.5:14
dispatchEvent @ load-scripts.php?c=0&load[]=jquery-core,jquery-migrate,utils,moxiejs,plupload&ver=4.9.5:14
trigger @ load-scripts.php?c=0&load[]=jquery-core,jquery-migrate,utils,moxiejs,plupload&ver=4.9.5:11
h @ load-scripts.php?c=0&load[]=jquery-core,jquery-migrate,utils,moxiejs,plupload&ver=4.9.5:14
start @ load-scripts.php?c=0&load[]=jquery-core,jquery-migrate,utils,moxiejs,plupload&ver=4.9.5:14
(anonymous) @ load-scripts.php?c=0&load[]=hoverIntent,common,admin-bar,heartbeat,autosave,wp-ajax-response,jquery-color,wp-lists,quicktags,jquery-query,admin-comments,sug&load[]=gest,jquery-ui-core,jquery-ui-widget,jquery-ui-mouse,jquery-ui-sortable,postbox,jquery-ui-position,jquery-ui-menu,wp-a11y,jquery&load[]=-ui-autocomplete,tags-suggest,tags-box,underscore,word-count,post,editor-expand,thickbox,shortcode,backbone,wp-util,wp-backbone,&load[]=media-models,wp-plupload,wp-mediaelement,wp-api-request,media-views,media-editor,media-audiovideo,mce-view,imgareaselect,image-e&load[]=dit,svg-painter,wp-auth-check,editor,wplink,media-upload,wp-embed&ver=4.9.5:462
dispatchEvent @ load-scripts.php?c=0&load[]=jquery-core,jquery-migrate,utils,moxiejs,plupload&ver=4.9.5:14
trigger @ load-scripts.php?c=0&load[]=jquery-core,jquery-migrate,utils,moxiejs,plupload&ver=4.9.5:11
(anonymous) @ load-scripts.php?c=0&load[]=jquery-core,jquery-migrate,utils,moxiejs,plupload&ver=4.9.5:14
(anonymous) @ load-scripts.php?c=0&load[]=jquery-core,jquery-migrate,utils,moxiejs,plupload&ver=4.9.5:11
setTimeout (async)
(anonymous) @ load-scripts.php?c=0&load[]=jquery-core,jquery-migrate,utils,moxiejs,plupload&ver=4.9.5:14
(anonymous) @ load-scripts.php?c=0&load[]=jquery-core,jquery-migrate,utils,moxiejs,plupload&ver=4.9.5:11
(anonymous) @ load-scripts.php?c=0&load[]=jquery-core,jquery-migrate,utils,moxiejs,plupload&ver=4.9.5:14
(anonymous) @ load-scripts.php?c=0&load[]=jquery-core,jquery-migrate,utils,moxiejs,plupload&ver=4.9.5:14
(anonymous) @ load-scripts.php?c=0&load[]=jquery-core,jquery-migrate,utils,moxiejs,plupload&ver=4.9.5:14
d @ load-scripts.php?c=0&load[]=jquery-core,jquery-migrate,utils,moxiejs,plupload&ver=4.9.5:11
(anonymous) @ load-scripts.php?c=0&load[]=jquery-core,jquery-migrate,utils,moxiejs,plupload&ver=4.9.5:11
(anonymous) @ load-scripts.php?c=0&load[]=jquery-core,jquery-migrate,utils,moxiejs,plupload&ver=4.9.5:14
(anonymous) @ load-scripts.php?c=0&load[]=jquery-core,jquery-migrate,utils,moxiejs,plupload&ver=4.9.5:14
(anonymous) @ load-scripts.php?c=0&load[]=jquery-core,jquery-migrate,utils,moxiejs,plupload&ver=4.9.5:14
d @ load-scripts.php?c=0&load[]=jquery-core,jquery-migrate,utils,moxiejs,plupload&ver=4.9.5:11
(anonymous) @ load-scripts.php?c=0&load[]=jquery-core,jquery-migrate,utils,moxiejs,plupload&ver=4.9.5:11
(anonymous) @ load-scripts.php?c=0&load[]=jquery-core,jquery-migrate,utils,moxiejs,plupload&ver=4.9.5:14
(anonymous) @ load-scripts.php?c=0&load[]=jquery-core,jquery-migrate,utils,moxiejs,plupload&ver=4.9.5:14
(anonymous) @ load-scripts.php?c=0&load[]=jquery-core,jquery-migrate,utils,moxiejs,plupload&ver=4.9.5:14
d @ load-scripts.php?c=0&load[]=jquery-core,jquery-migrate,utils,moxiejs,plupload&ver=4.9.5:11
e @ load-scripts.php?c=0&load[]=jquery-core,jquery-migrate,utils,moxiejs,plupload&ver=4.9.5:11
d @ load-scripts.php?c=0&load[]=jquery-core,jquery-migrate,utils,moxiejs,plupload&ver=4.9.5:14
(anonymous) @ load-scripts.php?c=0&load[]=jquery-core,jquery-migrate,utils,moxiejs,plupload&ver=4.9.5:14
d @ load-scripts.php?c=0&load[]=jquery-core,jquery-migrate,utils,moxiejs,plupload&ver=4.9.5:11
e @ load-scripts.php?c=0&load[]=jquery-core,jquery-migrate,utils,moxiejs,plupload&ver=4.9.5:11
addFile @ load-scripts.php?c=0&load[]=jquery-core,jquery-migrate,utils,moxiejs,plupload&ver=4.9.5:14
i.onchange @ load-scripts.php?c=0&load[]=jquery-core,jquery-migrate,utils,moxiejs,plupload&ver=4.9.5:14
(anonymous) @ load-scripts.php?c=0&load[]=jquery-core,jquery-migrate,utils,moxiejs,plupload&ver=4.9.5:11
(anonymous) @ load-scripts.php?c=0&load[]=jquery-core,jquery-migrate,utils,moxiejs,plupload&ver=4.9.5:11
d @ load-scripts.php?c=0&load[]=jquery-core,jquery-migrate,utils,moxiejs,plupload&ver=4.9.5:11
e @ load-scripts.php?c=0&load[]=jquery-core,jquery-migrate,utils,moxiejs,plupload&ver=4.9.5:11
dispatchEvent @ load-scripts.php?c=0&load[]=jquery-core,jquery-migrate,utils,moxiejs,plupload&ver=4.9.5:11
trigger @ load-scripts.php?c=0&load[]=jquery-core,jquery-migrate,utils,moxiejs,plupload&ver=4.9.5:11
q @ load-scripts.php?c=0&load[]=jquery-core,jquery-migrate,utils,moxiejs,plupload&ver=4.9.5:12
```

Just to show how desperate I was, I've tried deleting all the Files on the FTP-server and deleting the database , then reinstalling everything from scratch (even removed the cookies from my browser) just to make sure it's a clean install. Everything else works fine, but uploading an image doesn't work. I resized and saved the image from a JPEG to a smaller PNG, as some users online said that PNG worked better, but that didn't help either. Worth noting is that I am able to upload another, much smaller image, but the one I'm trying to upload is not over the limit. I even tried changing the limit to something farfetched like 64M.

I've checked the privileges on all the files and folders, they are set correctly.

I also tried all the .htaccess tricks that I found as suggestions on other threads. The only thing I haven't tried, and I don't think I even can, is to change from GD to ImageMagick as someone suggested. But I'm on a shared server and it doesn't have ImageMagick. That said, since I already tried changing the format and size of the image, it feels like it *shouldn't* be GD's fault.

Any other suggestions or idea are very welcome, I'm desperate to get this fixed or else it will be an image-less website!

P.S. I want to note that the very FIRST time I installed Wordpress on this server it worked just fine, the image was uploaded. But for various reason (trouble with the database) I had to reinstall it and that's when this started. But like I said I created a brand new database when I reinstalled it and it doesn't affect anything else.

**UPDATE**: So I just tested the limits of which images work and which don't, and I found something that may be a clue to someone else... the actual pixel resolution of the image doesn't seem to matter, but the image does seem to work as soon as it's compressed down to exactly 124Kb, I tested this on multiple images (although admittedly I didn't try 125Kb, but 126 and 127 didn't seem to work so I'm just assuming 125 wouldnt work either). I'm made sure the file upload limit in php.ini is 5M, so what else could be limiting uploads to 124Kb?

Comment: `/wp-admin/async-upload.php 404 (Not Found)` this file is missing in new install also?

Comment: The file is Not missing, I can see it on the FTP, and it has the same privileges as all the other files.

Comment: is that the whole error you got from the console? while uploading images?

Comment: Yes, that is the whole thing. In the actual image upload dialog window in Wordpress it says "HTTP Error".

Answer (score 0):

So I've solved the problem. Or more accurately, I asked my web host to solve the problem. After spending an hour or two testing the limits of what exactly can and can't be uploaded (see mu update in the original question), I started Googling on those limits and found suggestions that it had something to do with `MaxRequestLen` or `FcgidMaxRequestLen`. So I contacted my web host and they were kind enough to increase the limit to 20 mb. They also mentioned that `modsec` had been triggered so they disabled that as well, now I can upload large images again. Hope this helps some poor lost soul looking for answers :)